# Différence entre influer et influencer

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage

Y a-t-il une différence entre les deux verbes influer et influencer ? Si oui, dans quels cas utilisons-nous chacun de ces deux termes ?

Answer (score 3):

Il n'y a pas de différence de sens perceptible entre **[influencer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/influencer)** et **[influer sur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/influer)**, cependant, alors qu'**influer sur** était plus populaire qu'**influencer** jusqu'à la fin du XIXe siècle, **influencer** a largement pris le dessus depuis et ce verbe est aujourd'hui trois fois et demi plus utilisé qu'**influer sur**:

Source: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=influer%20sur%2Cinfluencer&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinfluer%20sur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinfluencer%3B%2Cc0)
[image]

Comment: False, there is a real difference. Actually 'Tu influences quelqu'un', 'Cela influe sur mon avenir'. Influencer is about people, and influer about things, facts.

Comment: @SteevenBrunner Not necessarily: "Les intempéries influencent les cours de la bourse" (facts), "Les parents influent sur le comportement de leurs enfants" (people)

Comment: @SteevenBrunner "Les écrits de Bergotte n'avaient nullement influé sur Morel" *Marcel Proust*, Le temps retrouvé.

Comment: @jilliagre Dans votre premier exemple, on agit sur le comportement et non pas sur une personne. L'autre exemple concernant les cours de la bourse est correct. Cependant je parle de l'utilisation moderne de ces termes.

Answer (score 2):

Les deux verbes ont forcément un sens très proche puisque influencer est un dérivé d'influer. Sont-ils synonymes ? Certains voient une différence d'emploi.

Le *Dictionnaire historique en langue française* nous dit que le verbe ***influer*** vient du latin classique *influere* qui signifie « couler, s'écouler ». On le trouve au XV<sup>e</sup> siècle avec le sens d'« exercer une influence (sur qqn. qqch.). Directement dérivé d'influer, le mot *influence* apparait au XIII<sup>e</sup> siècle. ***Influencer*** est apparu au XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle au sens d'exercer une « influence sur », il s'emploie aussi (attesté au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle) en parlant d'une chose et est devenu courant dans de nombreux domaines.

Si le sens des deux verbes est très proches (quasi synonymes pour certains) il faut souligner qu'ils ne se construisent pas pareil et que certains francophones sont parfois pris en délit de [mauvaise construction](http://www.bio-bulle.fr/alimentation-influencer-sante-de-vos-dents/). Pour résumer : on influe sur quelque chose/quelqu'un, on influence quelque chose/quelqu'un.

Beaucoup considèrent les deux verbes comme synonymes, mais les avis divergent, et préfèrent réserver l'emploi d'influer aux choses et concepts abstraits.

Extrait de SOQUIJ (Société québécoise d'information juridique) qui [résume ainsi](http://soquij.qc.ca/fr/ressources-pour-tous/chroniques-linguistiques/influencer-et-influer) (et prend parti) la polémique autour des verbes *influer* et *influencer* :

> Le verbe **influencer** doit avoir pour complément un nom désignant une personne ou un groupe de personnes : *Cette preuve a influencé le commissaire*. Quand le complément est un nom de chose, on emploiera plutôt **influer sur**: *Cette preuve a influé sur la décision du commissaire*.
>   Il est vrai que le *Nouveau Petit Robert* ne s'embarrasse pas de cette nuance puisqu'il se contente de donner au verbe influencer le sens d'« agir sur » et que l'exemple qu'il offre a pour complément un nom de chose mais, de tous les auteurs consultés, il est le seul à ne pas distinguer les deux verbes. Ne nous laissons pas influencer par les auteurs complaisants !

La BDL est [cependant moins catégorique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3860), comme le fait remarquer @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃.

À lire sur le blog *Parler Français* le billet [Mauvaises influences.](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/mauvaises-influences-a117646010)

Comment: Je ne vois pas en quoi le titre de l'article est faux. Il s'agit d'*influencer quelqu'un*, en l'occurrence Sarkozy, *sur un sujet*, en l'occurrence l'Islam. Comme on aurait pu dire *influer sur Sarkozy sur l'Islam*, mais ç'aurait été assez laid. Si on reprend ton exemple : *Cette preuve a influencé le commissaire sur la culpabilité du suspect*. Cependant j'aurais utilisé *à propos de* plutôt que *sur*.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Tu as tt à fait raison, j'ai mis un autre lien, on en trouve !

Comment: Ah ah ah joli. Quelle horreur.